# Where does the CPU scheduler sit in a layered OS design

Tags: computer-architecture, operating-systems, cpu

In a layered approach to OS design, each layer can only access routines from the layers below itself.

For example, say I had two levels: memory management and the CPU scheduler

Where does the CPU scheduler sit in a layered OS design?

My understanding is that it must be above the memory management component, since the scheduler needs access to the routines in the memory management layer to be able to select new processes from memory to place on the CPUs ready queue.